# How is it possible to retrieve ERC-20 tokens sent to a testnet?

Tags: erc-20, testnets

I'm wondering if it possible to retrieve ERC-20 tokens sent to a testnet wallet. In my case, the testnet private key actually opens an other Ethereum wallet completely different from what the testnet says. Thus the tokens sent are actually in a mainnet wallet whos private key is unknown.

Comment: What software do you use? Your private key should generate the same address on both testnet and mainnet.

Comment: I used this site https://wallet.zilliqa.com/wallet/base to create a testnet wallet. Zilliqa is still under testing and the mainnet is to be launched later in the q3. The private key that this wallet generates do not actually retrieve the public address they mention. I used MEW to check them.

Comment: Unfortunately, in that case you may be out of luck. Your best chance is probably to open an issue [on their github](https://github.com/Zilliqa/Zilliqa).